How do I create an master HLS playlist using existing multiple .m3u8 playlists
Is it possible to play multiple playlists using master.m3u8. As the clip1 and clip2 m3u8 are in different folder structures. I tried to play it but only 1st clip seems to be playing.
master.m3u8:
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2305600,RESOLUTION=852x480,CODECS="avc1.640034,mp4a.40.2"
main/clips/new/2024/clip1.m3u8
main/clips/2023/clip2.m3u8

clip1.m3u8:
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-VERSION:3

#EXTINF:10,
clip/1.ts
#EXTINF:10,
clip/2.ts
#EXTINF:10,
clip/3.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST

clip2.m3u8
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-VERSION:3

#EXTINF:10,
clip/1.ts
#EXTINF:10,
clip/2.ts
#EXTINF:10,
clip/3.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST

I tried to play the master.m3u8, which includes multiple m3u8 file path included in it. But only 1st path clip seems to be playing.

You could concatenate the two clips' contents into a new playlist and put a #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag between them

This says it better: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50859334/22147

I don't want to combine those different file content .ts files, as I have a lot more like thousands of ts files. Is there a possibility like I can use the references to the m3u8 paths similar to master.m3u8


"Is there a possibility like I can use the references to the m3u8 paths similar to master.m3u8"

Since you're using VLC, you could try creating a playlist file that points to M3U8 files. VLC can play .pls playlist files. You give it this one file and the multiple M3U8 files should play in sequence.
PLS is a simple text format:
[playlist]
NumberOfEntries=2
File1=https://www.website.com/main/clips/new/2024/clip1.m3u8
File2=https://www.website.com/main/clips/2023/clip2.m3u8

Edit:

"I want to provide a master url to clients which looks like website.com/master.m3u8 And that should contain many associated m3u8 file paths"

In HLS, a master.m3u8 is considered as a configuration file. It cannot be a playlist. No public/free M3U8 player is programmed to read the config file only and then use it as a playlist file.
If client-side means "my users are watching via VLC" then from testing, only PLS will work for your idea. For testing, save the text below as test.pls and open that file in VLC:
[playlist]
NumberOfEntries=2
File1=https://cdn.bitmovin.com/content/assets/art-of-motion-dash-hls-progressive/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa_video_360_800000.m3u8
File2=https://live-par-2-cdn-alt.livepush.io/live/bigbuckbunnyclip/tracks-v4a1/mono.m3u8

Otherwise you have to code your own player (eg: make a web player that cycles through a text list of M3U8 urls, then through javascript it should detect the ended event and simply reload the next M3U8 playlist and repeat process until end of text list).
Alternative to a custom player code, is to use coding to edit some custom made playlist.m3u8 that lists all TS files added from the various playlists. This means using some file Browser API to select M3U8 playlists and then also have a function that updates a String with lines from the other M3U8s until you have concatenated them all into one text String. On saving that String as M3U8 it should then work.

I want to provide a master url to clients which looks like
https://www.website.com/master.m3u8
And that should contain many associated m3u8 file paths

In HLS, a master.m3u8 is considered as a configuration file. It cannot be a playlist. No public/free M3U8 player is programmed to read the config file only as though it was a playlist file. If client-side means "my users are watching via VLC"  then from testing, only PLS will work. Otherwise you have to code your own player (eg: a web player or use code to create a new playlist whose TS file paths are extracted from other M3U8 playlists. What programming language(s) do you know that you could edit such text files with?

Yes, I know, clubbing the ts file together will work for sure. I use c# language

I tried to concatenate the 3 video clips (video 1 - 25.48,video 2 - 00.26, video 3- 32:56 )contents into a new playlist and put a #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag. When I try to play I see the total length of the video as 59.03, but after playing the video1 after 25.48 its keeps on buffering and doesn't play rest of the video. Any inputs would be appreciated.

I used something like this
#EXTM3U . #EXTINF:10.000, 2024/4/27/12/58/media/hls/1080p/0.ts #EXTINF:10.000, 2024/4/27/12/58/media/hls/1080p/1.ts #EXTINF:10.005, . . '#EXTINF:4.758, 2024/4/27/12/58/media/hls/1080p/149.ts EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY #EXTINF:10.027, 2024/4/27/13/28/media/hls/1080p48/0.ts #EXTINF:10.987, 2024/4/27/13/28/media/hls/1080p48/1.ts #EXTINF:5.825, EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY #EXTINF:10.006, 2024/4/27/13/29/media/hls/1080p/0.ts #EXTINF:10.005, 2024/4/27/13/29/media/hls/1080p/1.ts #EXTINF:0.065, . . . 2024/4/27/13/29/media/hls/1080p/191.ts #EXT-X-ENDLIST

Hi. You don't need the EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY parts when you change folders. Just carrying on listing from new folder as you do same as if it was a file from the old (previous) folder. The file's name being 0.ts is just a file name. It doesn't affect playback sequencing, and also since nothing is resetted then there's no need for these DISCONTINUITY signals.

#EXTINF:10.000, 2024/4/27/12/58/media/hls/1080p/5.ts can be followed by something like #EXTINF:10.005, 2024/4/27/13/29/media/hls/1080p/1.ts etc... PS: Do not mix video types (eg 1080p cannot be mixed with 1080p48 or 720p etc...)
